# Can every encryption algorithm encrypt ASCII keys?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, cryptography

Example, an encryption algorithm based on Chebyshev polynomials. The domain of the message must be in [-1,1] while the ASCII table is 0 - 255 how does it encrypt it?

Chebyshev polynomials: http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/CAG/papers/Cheb.pdf

Comment: You *encode* the data to be encrypted into the character set of the encryption algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalize your input from `0-255` range to `[-1,1]`: `N(x) = x/128 - 1` and use `N(x)` as input to your encryption algorithm instead of `x`. For other ranges just use different normalization function.